# When Someone Answers Your Question Does It Change The Order In Which It's Listed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

If there is activity on a question does it move it up the default sort order....or will it only show up on the first page for a few minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Answering a question will bump your question to the top of the Active sort.

For Stack Overflow, [the front page is only partially affected by the active sort](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/), so it isn't guaranteed to shoot up to the top from that alone. But for other sites and for all users who browse under Active, it will be bumped to the top.